# Link tag not working and has extra border on it in a popup dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, hyperlink, dialog

I have a problem with an `<a>` link not working with a popout dialog on http://surtilub.com/productos.html. There is also a border appearing around the `<a>` when the popup first appears.

To see this, you can click click on "Leer más" on any product.  Why aren't my links working, and what is causing the border to show up?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your pdf links are broken. To be sure that they work, paste them directly into your browser window and make sure they load. you need to update your pdf files, remove any spaces in the filenames, and then update your links. for the borders, to remove them the css property is 'border:0 none;'

Answer (score 0):

You can try using javascript.

```
<a onclick="window.open(this.href,'_blank');return false;" href="http://some_other_site.com/whatever.pdf">Your other site</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your links aren't working because they are not properly url encoded (see [w3 URL Encoding](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGs/ref_urlencode.asp)). For example, your first link in the first item is

```
fichas/300V 15W50 2Lts. Ficha Tecnica.pdf
```

but should be

```
fichas/300V%2015W50%202Lts.%20Ficha%20Tecnica.pdf
```

The CSS error you're seeing is because of your css file jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom.js.
In there, there is a section that looks like

```
/* Component containers
----------------------------------*/
.ui-widget { font-family: Lucida Grande, Lucida Sans, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 1.1em; height: 200px; }
.ui-widget .ui-widget { font-size: 1em; }
.ui-widget input, .ui-widget select, .ui-widget textarea, .ui-widget button { font-family:   Lucida Grande, Lucida Sans, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 1em; }
/*.ui-widget-content { border: 1px solid #a6c9e2; background: #fcfdfd url(images/ui-bg_inset-    hard_100_fcfdfd_1x100.png) 50% bottom repeat-x; color: #222222; } */
.ui-widget-content a { color: #222222; }
.ui-widget-header {color: #ffffff; font-weight: bold; }
.ui-widget-header a { color: #ffffff; }
```

Removing `.ui-widget-content a { color: #222222; }` resolves the issue.  You could also override it in your own css file if you have a need for it.

Comment: @Diegolops, if this did not work for you or you need additional help with this, please let me know, otherwise, if this answer was helpful and correct, please accept it.